# Error parsing json content through JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm using the json_script template tag from django to take a json from a context view.

I receive the json like this

```
{{rules|json_script:"rules"}}

<script lang="javascript">
    const rules = JSON.parse($('#rules').text())
</script>
```

this is what i receive from `{{rules|json_script:"rules"}}`

```
<script id="rules" type="application/json">{"id": 10, "string": "demo", "profile": "Alumno Demo", "license": "Licencia no facturable por usuario demo", "field": "codigo_usuario", "include": true, "order": 1, "uppercase_sensitive": false, "dateadded": "2020-05-11T08:06:35Z", "billable": false}</script>
```

But when i try to JSON.parse I receive this error:

```
VM760:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 5
```

What am I doing wrong? If I copy the content of the script it seems like a correct json.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you `console.log($('#rules').text())` and post the output?

Answer (score 2):

**Actually $('#rules').text() is returning a jQuery n.fn.init function.**

Looking at the code of jQuery library:

```
`var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
   return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
};`
```

it returns an empty function in case it is unable to find an element on DOM.

**What you can do:**

**1**. Use Basic javascript method getElementsByTagName like this:

`document.getElementsByTagName('script')`

this will return an array of script elements, in your case you will get 2 elements and just use text attribute to get script tag contents.

`JSON.parse(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].text)`

**2**. You can also declare a variable in your script and parse JSON like this:

`var stringifiedJson = {"id": 10, "string": "demo", "profile": "Alumno Demo", "license": "Licencia no facturable por usuario demo", "field": "codigo_usuario", "include": true, "order": 1, "uppercase_sensitive": false, "dateadded": "2020-05-11T08:06:35Z", "billable": false};
JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);`

Comment: You're right, but I dont get one thing:

Why if I use getElementByIid I get:

<div class="collapse" id="rules">
...
</div>

and when I get use getElementsByTagName('script')[20].text I get

 <script id="rules" type="application/json">{"id": 10, "string": "demo", "profile": "Alumno Demo", "license": "Licencia no facturable por usuario demo", "field": "codigo_usuario", "include": true, "order": 1, "uppercase_sensitive": false, "dateadded": "2020-05-11T08:06:35Z", "billable": false}</script>

Comment: Just because scripts elements doesn't work with an id attribute, it can only have async, charset, src, type, defer.